# Find and replace sporatic results

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I would like to create a simple (or so I thought) macro to rename cells in a workbook.  The workbook contains about a dozen sheets.  First I started with 2 input boxes that require the user to input the old and new names.  I then used the macro recorder to determine the proper code to replace within a workbook vs. just a single sheet.  I manipulated the code to use the strings from the input boxes to determine the 'Find what:' and 'Replace with:' values.  Below is the code.

```
Option Explicit

'PROCEDURES-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Rename_Project()

'---Procedure Description/Notes---------------------------------------------------------------
    'Macro Overview:
        'Simple macro that will rename all instances of a project in the workbook (all sheets).
        'The user will be prompted for the old project name then the new name.

'---Variable Declarations---------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strPrjNew As String
Dim strPrjOld As String

'---Code--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Launch input box prompting for old PROJECT NAME
    strPrjOld = InputBox("Enter existing Project Name:", "Existing Project")
    If Len(strPrjOld) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    'Launch input box prompting for new PROJECT NAME
    strPrjNew = InputBox("Enter NEW Project Name:", "New Project")
    If Len(strPrjNew) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
'
    Selection.Replace What:=strPrjOld, Replacement:= _
        strPrjNew, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

As you could see, this is pretty straightforward.  The issue that I am facing is that this will only run if I manually go to the replace command then change the 'Within:' option to Workbook.  I could run the macro all day long after that with no issues.  Is there a way to set the options to Workbook instead of Sheet within a macro?  I did this when recording the macro, however it does not seem to record that part for some reason???

I apologize in advance if this is covered elsewhere.  I searched many times and was not able to find a solution...this may be due to my lack of understanding as to what to look for.

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps the last response in [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=118754) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `Application.Selection` property which will return a context-dependant range (which, from the description you give, does not seem to be your purpose), I would suggest to use a `Worksheet` object as reference for the replacement.

If you want to replace on all worksheets of the workbook, I'd suggest to iterate over the worksheets:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        .Cells.Replace What:=strPrjOld, Replacement:= _
            strPrjNew, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
Next ws
```

else, if you want to replace on one worksheet only :

```
Workseets("sheet1").Cells.Replace What:=strPrjOld, Replacement:= _
    strPrjNew, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Many thanks chuff & d-stroyer.  I was able to use the code from d-stroyer which worked beautifully.  Appreciate the assistance!!